# k-means|| in PySpark

Tags: machine-learning, k-means, pyspark

I'm trying to apply k-means$\|$ clustering in PySpark.

According to [this paper](http://theory.stanford.edu/~sergei/papers/vldb12-kmpar.pdf), there is an oversampling factor, $l$, that would affect the model's cost.

I couldn't find any parameter regarding oversampling factor in PySpark's k-means function. There is a parameter called `initializationSteps` but there is no proper definition for that.

Is there a way I could use oversampling factor in k-means function?

Answer (score 2):

Based on the paper you set k but want to sample greater than k and apply the log calculation.

I would recommend using the foreach function. Where you could say foreach() apply further reach than k.

where the following aglo from the paper could be interpreted as follows.

Algorithm 2 k-means||(k, ) initialization.

```
1: C ← sample a point uniformly at random from X
2: ψ ← φX(C)
3: for O(log ψ) times do
4: C 0 ← sample each point x ∈ X independently with probability px =·d2(x,C) φX(C)
5: C ← C ∪ C0
6: end for
7: For x ∈ C, set wx to be the number of points in X closer to x than any other point inC
8: Recluster the weighted points in C into k clusters
```

instructions:

```
get points of k = 2
points [(1,1),(1,2),(2,2)]
```

centroid is placed in middle for this example and

```
c1 = [(1,1),(1,2)]
```

This was achieved with the over sample of Euclid `foreach()` point that satisfies the over sampling requirement.

see example [here](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.2.0/mllib-clustering.html) which uses for each:

```
# Cluster the data into two classes using PowerIterationClustering
model = PowerIterationClustering.train(similarities, 2, 10)

model.assignments().foreach(lambda x: print(str(x.id) + " -> " + str(x.cluster)))
```

So you will need to write the distance into the lambda.(if you provide code easier to help you).

K distance = k distance on perimeter which is the bottom red line in diagram
[image]

```
 .foreach(lambda x: kdistance[get average] + then check prob(k prime) of k)
```

share some code and sample data please

Answer (score 0):

Hope [this article](http://www.bmc.com/blogs/k-means-clustering-apache-spark/) will give you a headstart on the same.